# Swift Functional Programming: JSON parsing

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, functional-programming

I'm relatively new to functional programming with Swift and trying to parse Json using this [blog post](http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/json-parsing-in-swift.html) I found by Chris Eidhof.

The problem I run into is when I try parse to a struct with an optional property e.g. in my example I changed 'let name: String' to 'let name: String?'

Here is Chris Eidhof's code, with the small modification that I make the url property an optional (and removed extraneous code).

I get the error: Function signature `Int -> String? -> Blog` is not compatible with the expected type `Int -> (String -> Blog)`. This makes sense to me as I understand it's expecting 'String' and not 'String?'. The error appears in the `parseBlog` function

```
import Foundation

let parsedJSON : [String:AnyObject] = [
    "stat": "ok",
    "blogs": [
        "blog": [
            [
                "id" : 73,
                "name" : "Bloxus test",
            ],
            [
                "id" : 74,
                "name" : "Manila Test",
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

struct Blog {
    let id: Int
    let name: String?
}

func parseBlog(blog: AnyObject) -> Blog? {
    let mkBlog = curry {id, name in Blog(id: id, name: name) }
    return asDict(blog) >>>= {
        mkBlog <*> int($0, key: "id")
            <*> string($0, key:"name")
    }
}

func parseJSON() {
    let blogs = dictionary(parsedJSON, key: "blogs") >>>= {
        array($0, key: "blog") >>>= {
            join($0.map(parseBlog))
        }
    }
    print("posts: \(blogs)")
}

func toURL(urlString: String) -> NSURL {
    return NSURL(string: urlString)!
}


func asDict(x: AnyObject) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    return x as? [String:AnyObject]
}


func join<A>(elements: [A?]) -> [A]? {
    var result : [A] = []
    for element in elements {
        if let x = element {
            result += [x]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return result
}

infix operator  <*> { associativity left precedence 150 }
func <*><A, B>(l: (A -> B)?, r: A?) -> B? {
    if let l1 = l {
        if let r1 = r {
            return l1(r1)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func flatten<A>(x: A??) -> A? {
    if let y = x { return y }
    return nil
}

func array(input: [String:AnyObject], key: String) ->  [AnyObject]? {
    let maybeAny : AnyObject? = input[key]
    return maybeAny >>>= { $0 as? [AnyObject] }
}

func dictionary(input: [String:AnyObject], key: String) ->  [String:AnyObject]? {
    return input[key] >>>= { $0 as? [String:AnyObject] }
}

func string(input: [String:AnyObject], key: String) -> String? {
    return input[key] >>>= { $0 as? String }
}

func number(input: [NSObject:AnyObject], key: String) -> NSNumber? {
    return input[key] >>>= { $0 as? NSNumber }
}

func int(input: [NSObject:AnyObject], key: String) -> Int? {
    return number(input,key: key).map { $0.integerValue }
}

func bool(input: [NSObject:AnyObject], key: String) -> Bool? {
    return number(input,key: key).map { $0.boolValue }
}


func curry<A,B,R>(f: (A,B) -> R) -> A -> B -> R {
    return { a in { b in f(a,b) } }
}

infix operator  >>>= {}

func >>>= <A,B> (optional : A?, f : A -> B?) -> B? {
    return flatten(optional.map(f))
}
```

I think the cause of it `<*>` operator, which is a functional call that only gets executed when all optional values are non-nil. Hence I created a new operator `<?>` which is similar to `<*>`, but allows for the input to be optional (I think)

```
infix operator  <?> { associativity left precedence 150 }
func <?><A, B>(l: (A? -> B)?, r: A?) -> B? {
    if let l1 = l {
        return l1(r)
    }
    return nil
}
```

If I then change the `parseBlog` function to the following, the error disappears.

```
func parseBlog(blog: AnyObject) -> Blog? {
    let mkBlog = curry {id, name in Blog(id: id, name: name) }
    return asDict(blog) >>>= {
        mkBlog <*> int($0, key: "id")
            <?> string($0, key:"name")
    }
}
```

I am not quite sure why this works as I am still wrapping my head around some of these concepts. I have a vague understanding of why `<?>` works but can't quite put it into words. Any clarity would be really appreciated!